# Package is not searchable in bower

Tags: search, package, bower

I had created a bower package of the library:- "https://github.com/umakantp/jsmart"

This was searchable earlier in the bower search "http://bower.io/search/" with keywords like jsmart, javascript templates or owner:umakantp

Yesterday I released a new version of the library and since then it is not visible in the bower search.

If I run "bower info jsmart" on cmd line, it's information is available. Search on cmd line works using "bower search jsmart"

I looked into manifest file "bower.json", it is in the desired format. (Even jQuery uses the same)

What could be the reason for not appearing in the bower package search?